# Connecting Java app from a PC to XAMPP server on another PC

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm working on a personal project that includes a Java app connecting to a XAMPP SQL database. The app connects to the database perfectly on the same PC as the database is being hosted on. The program uses a singleton class.

Code:

```java
private Connector() {
    String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, pass);
        System.out.println("Connection success!");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Connection failed!");
    }
}
```

I wanted to take a step further and be able to put the app on my laptop and connect to the database on my PC. I went into XAMPP and changed the "httpd-xampp.conf" file so that it allows local connections, and when I went on my laptop I tried opening phpMyAdmin from the browser and it worked!

Now I put the app on my laptop but instead of the host being:

```
String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database";
```

I found the local IP of my PC and on my laptop changed the host to be:

```
String host = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.8/my_database";
```

The connection failed so I tried setting up a different user that allows any host to connect and has full access just in case. Still the same error happens.

I checked my firewall, but there was no entry that disables the connection, but anyways I was able to connect to phpMyAdmin through the browser through my laptop.

Here is the part I changed in the Xampp config file:

```
<Directory "N:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try port forwarding the application / port on the PC just to be sure it's not the firewall as other than that, I don't see what would prevent the connection.

[Here](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html) is a link on port forwarding on Windows if you need it.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think my router doesn't support port forwarding but I'll give it a try and get back to you